# Anki + TexLive via Tug error: I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'! (-> LaTeX (pdfTeX) Error: Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

Tags: pdftex, anki

I downloaded Anki via AUR, opened it and created a flashcard using LaTeX. I previewed it and first go the error that I had to install dvisvgm/dvipng although dvipng was already installed... Installed dvisvgm, got rid of the error. Then, I got the error:

```
Error executing ⁨latex⁩.
Generated file: ⁨/tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex⁩
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
mktexfmt: No such file or directory
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

I fixed the problem by adding in /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf

```
TEXFORMATS = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c//
```

Edit: The following part is unnecessary as the issue lied deeper than that in the step before.

Reloaded everything and now get the following error everytime I preview or "normally" view a card with LaTeX.

```
Error executing ⁨latex⁩.
Generated file: ⁨/tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex⁩

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

After making changes in general I restarted Anki.

1. I tested all the different types of LaTeX environments in Anki, all with the same result.
2. I ran fmtutil in all sorts of variations: fmtutil-sys --all, fmtutil-user --all, sudo fmtutil-sys --all, fmtutil-sys --all as root (su), didn't solve the issue.
3. I took a look at the /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anki/latex.py file in order to see how the svg-file is created. I executed the commands in there manually in /tmp/anki_temp/ and they work there just fine (except the option --exact which I then deleted but I don't think it changed anything). To edit the build process properly, I downloaded the Anki addon https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/937148547 where interestingly the --exact-option wasn't included. I tried different "compilers" (although some of them use each other, I am not exactly familiar on how this is going) latex, pdflatex, latexmk, all of them didn't work with the same error, except the "(preloaded format=...) was changed.
4. I thought that the commands might be executed in the wrong directory, but I compared the logs by manually making the error and it didn't work as did cd-commands in the build process didn't work, but it doesn't seem to be the error anyways.
5. I recognized that I had multiple latex.fmt files because I had files for all users in /usr/local/texlive/2023 and one for my local user ~/.texlive*, don't quiet remeber the exact folder name in local user because I deleted it, but it didn't resolve it either.
6. I thought about if the issue arose when solving the

```
"I can't find the format file 'Latex.fmt'!"
```

error, but each time I changed something in the /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf file, I got the error back. I still think this might be the source but my understanding and knowledge isn't enough to find out what the problem is exactly

7. Manually adding the svg-file and reloaded the flashcard, I got some more errors of lots of missing maps. Don't know if this error has something to do with the "I'm stymied"-one.

Comment: you have edited your local texmf.cnf it's hard to say what to do, deleting the local config probably a good start. `TEXFORMATS = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c//` you should never need to do that.  latex is always in the default path, if you are needing to set it you have errors elsewhere. Note that is the path for upstream tex installed from tug but `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) ` is the arch system tex installed from your linux package manager. You could use either but you have to decide which and set the PATH to ensure one or the other

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I deleted "TEXFORMATS = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c//" out of my texmf.cnf.
For the PATH problem: Can you explain the problem for me, I don't really get it? Do you mean Anki searches in the "tug-PATH" but I have the "Arch-PATH"?

Additional info:
I updated the first error in my original post.
I installed TexLive via https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live point 1.1.1 and therefore added "export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH" in my ~/.bashrc.
The latex.fmt file is located at /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt

Comment: that fmt is the one from upstream texlive, the log you show is your Linux distrib, which would explain the format error

Comment: as you have installed the texlive using the arch linux package manager you should not be using or setting any paths related to `/usr/local/texlive/2023` which is the location of an upstream tex installed directly from tug. You are mixing your two tex systems so forcing the fatal format error.

Comment: Thank you so much! The general idea that the problem lies in the two different tex-systems was absolutely correct! I didn't install texlive via pacman (arch linux package manager) but the "upstream tex"  via tug (via the Arch Wiki). The problem was that Anki was looking for the arch-based-tex-live. I changed the build process to make Anki use the upstream tex and it worked!

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood some of your arch references, but you certainly have the arch tex installed as you showed its log `(TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)`  however as you have running code, could you post an answer to get this off the unanswered list, thanks.

Comment: I don't quiet know why I have both installed but yeah. I did post an answer. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to David Carlisle (see comments under my question) for finding the root of the problem:

TexLive installed via tug vs. Arch-Packaged-TexLive.

I seemed to have both installed but mainly worked with the tug-install.
However, Anki seemed to use the Arch-Packaged-TexLive which didn't work.

1. I downloaded the Anki addon to change the build process: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/937148547
2. I opened the plugin (in Anki Tools - Add-ons - Edit LaTeX build process)
3. Replaced in "svgCommands" latex with the output of `which latex` and did the same with dvisvgm replacing it with the output of `which dvisvgm`.
4. Restart Anki